# Opencart Check if current page is product

Tags: opencart

Does OpenCart Version 2.3.0.2 have some methods to check in header or footer .tpl files that current page is product? Example `if (is_product) { // do something }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, But you can create it.

**File:**

> catalog/controller/common/header.php

**Find:**

```
return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
```

**Add Before:**

```
$data['is_product'] = isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'product/product';
```

**File:**

> catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl

**Add where you need:**

```
<?php if (!empty($is_product)) { ?>
    <p>This is the product page</p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>This is not the product page</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to check if your session has product.  `$this->session->data['product_id']` You can check it anywhere. You can write the product to the session... for example:

```
$this->session->data['product_id'] = /*your product_id*/;
```

And now you can retrieve this product anywhere.